# How can I show an inform JDialog before System.exit() in Java Swing? (Closed)

Tags: java, swing

In my simple login window, I added Action Listener to my login button. On pressing the button, the program will check the information the user entered, if they enter the wrong info 3 times then program will create a new JDialog to inform user, after that program will shut down.

My problem is that the JDialog appears blank then the program shutting down.

Here is my code

```
btnLogIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            char[] pass = pssPassWord.getPassword();
            String pss = new String(pass);

            if (!pss.toString().equals("admin") || !txtUserName.getText().equals("Adminuser")){
                if (attempts == 2){
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            new Inform("You entered the wrong info 3 times, the program will shut down");
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                System.exit(0);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });



                }else {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            new Info("Wrong info, please check the info");
                        }
                    });
                    attempts += 1;
                }
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
```

This is my Inform class:

```
public class Inform extends JDialog{

private JPanel pnlInform;
private JLabel lblInform;
private JButton btnOK;

public Inform(String info){
    setContentPane(pnlInform);
    lblInform.setText(info);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

}

My IDE is Intellij IDEA and I use form class to create GUI, so there is no declaration for the elements.

Comment: Does it close immediately? Then you maybe need to give the `Info` some time to show.

Comment: Why `invokeLater()` in `actionPerformed()`? Aren't you already running on the EDT?

Comment: @KevinWallis It will close after 1 second because I used Thread.sleep(1000). Before that, the Info JDialog appears but is blank.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland I have just started programming Java recently and I thought it would be safer, I will notice in my next programs. Thanks.

Comment: Also, don't `sleep()` on the EDT; just exit when the dialog closes. Start a swing`Timer` that calls `exit()` in case the user doesn't respond.

Comment: Kindly put your Inform full class code.

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile, because you may not use `try` as a variable name. When you ask about code that doesn't work, post the code that doesn't work. Not something else.

Comment: @JBNizet I edited my code. In my code, I use my mother tongue for name so I have translated it wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt add any components to the `Inform` dialog since `pnlInform` is not constructed and resolvs to `null` and it will through `contentPane cannot be set to null.`
**Solutions** : Construct the components (pnlInform,lblInform,btnOK) , then add them to the dialog. Below you can find a full functioning code:

```
package test.q5;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Inform extends JDialog {

    private JPanel pnlInform=new JPanel();
    private JLabel lblInform=new JLabel();
    private JButton btnOK=new JButton("OK");

    public Inform(String info) {
//      setContentPane(pnlInform);
        add(pnlInform);
        lblInform.setText(info);
        pnlInform.add(lblInform);
        pnlInform.add(btnOK);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Inform("Hello");
    }
}
```

However , you still need to do some formatting for the message, please feel free to add it as another question to be able to help.

Comment: I so glad that you help me this much. This is my first question on StackOverFlow so I have not been accustomed to anything yet. I have change my code use Timer to make it exit after an amount of time. Anyway I am appreciated for your help. Maybe I should closed this question. Thanks a again.